# How to add style to second-to-last only if total number of children are even?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So, I have a dynamic number of list items and I would like to apply a style to the second to last.... IF only there are an even number of elements.

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply style to the Three li element in the above case, but nothing if as follows.

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of two selectors like in the below snippet.

When the parent has an even number of children elements, the second last element must be an odd numbered one and so if an element matches both `nth-last-child(2)` and `nth-child(odd)` then it means that it is the second last child of the parent and the parent has an even number of elements.

```css
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

You could combine `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-last-child(2)`.

This works because `:nth-last-child(2)` will select the second to last child, and `:nth-child(odd)` only selects it if it's odd. If the total number of children is even, then the second to last child will always be odd.

```css
ul li:nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(2) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```